# bubbles within input fields - How?

Tags: web-applications, input, uitextfield, text-files

I want to develop bubbles within input fields.  Does anyone know a good tutorial or at least the *actual* name so I can look myself?  I have provided examples below that illustrate what I mean, within the "to" field.

**Examples:**

Hotmail:
http://thesocialmediaguide.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/email-to-Facebook.jpg

Comment: or here: http://api.ning.com/files/EPrO8gi2ajoMlAlkWwXukdjDo1OGHCvporO0Lc4AaKaFamh0OFJov7qunUxhSbnqm2VVp2QgyLlWxqowgCBvbQ9veDzijb9E/facebook_message.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a tutorial, but you can take a look at the source code of the ExtJS [SuperBoxSelect](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?69090-Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect-as-seen-on-facebook-and-hotmail) component to understand how they did it.